# Warning trying to get a string from an array ,iOS

Tags: ios

My program works OK, but I get this warning when compiling:

> format not a string literal and no format arguments

RomanosBasicos is an array of Strings:

```
RomanosBasicos=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"M",@"CM",@"D",@"CD",@"C",@"XC",@"L",@"XL",@"X",@"IX",@"V",@"IV",@"I" , nil];
```

and I get the warning  in this line:

```
temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:[RomanosBasicos objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Thanks for your help!.

Comment: NSArray gives NSObject, not NSString. Cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:[RomanosBasicos objectAtIndex:i]];
```

use

```
temp = [temp stringByAppendingString:[RomanosBasicos objectAtIndex:i]];
```

But if you want to use `stringByAooendingFormat:` then you have to do this

```
temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [RomanosBasicos objectAtIndex:i]];
```

I think you get it now what that warning means.

Comment: To add on to this, the reason for the warning is that feeding in a format string as a variable is very dangerous, and opens you up to potential security breaches if somehow an arbitrary format string can be fed in here.  This is one of the many reasons why I always treat warnings as errors in my compiler settings when dealing with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [temp stringByAppendingString:[RomanosBasicos objectAtIndex:i]]; instead?

Answer (score 0):

`stringByAppendingFormat:` is expecting an [Formatted NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) with arguments. It seems from your program that you actually want `stringByAppendingString:` like so:

```
temp = [temp stringByAppendingString:[RomanosBasicos objectAtIndex:i]];
```